# How to optimise views with multiple field collection?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I created a views reports page with multiple field collections (10), I added the field collection in relationships in advanced option to get the fields inside the field collection. this works great I get all the data that I need.
but here's the problem. If the page have the data on it, it takes time to load the page.

Example: If I have thousands of data in views reports page, it takes time to load the page, almost 1 minute(some times it keeps on loading). though I only display 10 items on each row using pagination/views lightpager but stills the page loading is slow,

My question: is how can I optimise my views reports page with multiple field collection relationships in my current setup, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Note: The data should always up to date. that's why I don't cache the views.

Thank you!

Comment: Why cant you use Views Cache?

Comment: It should show the latest data,

Answer (score 1):

As per your reply, you dont want to use Cache, so I can suggest a module for this, [Views Accelerator](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accelerator). It increases the performance of the view.

> Views Accelerator can bring about significant speed improvements on
>   sites with views that cannot be cached normally, for instance because
>   the views depend on an aspect of the visitor's session, like their
>   location. Views Accelerator serves up two modes of operation.
>
> Analysis mode: Switched on from the module's configuration page,
>   admin/config/system/views-accelerator, this displays at the top of the
>   screen a performance summary for each view on the page. If performance
>   is already great, tell your boss or customer. If it isn't, take a
>   screenshot of the performance summary and proceed with the Accelerator
>   mode: On views that could do with a boost, find and click the Caching
>   option link in the Advanced section of the Views UI. It will reveal a
>   new pseudo-caching option: None. Post-execution optimized by Views
>   Accelerator. Select that. Revisit the page with the view(s) and
>   compare performance stats to the screenshot you took earlier. Win?
>   Then tell your boss or customer.